# Find the LAN option in my laptop dell N5010 in its network and sharing centre?

Tags: wireless-networking, email

I have purchased a Dell Inspiron N5010 (with Windows 7). I have downloaded and installed the ethernet driver but I can't find the LAN option in network and sharing centre.

Comment: Have you installed the driver? Does the interface appear in the Device Manager?

Comment: Are you referring to the Network and sharing overview page or change adapter settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find network devices to configure them, do this:

1. Start menu, type in "view network connections"

If you are trying to find the device to uninstall or re-install or update driver, do this:

1. Start Menu, right cilck on computer, go Manage.
2. In the new window, in the left panel, go to Device Manager.
3. Click on the triangle to the left of "Network adaptors"
4. Have fun